# Implementing an interface using an asynchronous WCF service?

Tags: wcf, asynchronous, interface

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to implement a .NET interface, where the interface method has to return something and you are implementing that particular interface method with an asynchronous WCF service?

Hopefully you should already see the issue I am encountering.

Here is the interface:

```
    public interface IDataService
    {
        IDataServiceResponse SendDataRequest();
    }
```

IDataServiceResponse is supposed to represent a simple container that holds the result of my asynchronous WCF callback.

Here is the code snippet where I am implementing the interface method, SendDataRequest()

```
        public IDataServiceResponse SendDataRequest()
        {
            InitializeDataServiceParameters();

            // Call the web service asynchronously, here....
            _client.BeginQueryJobs(_parameters, DataServiceQueryCallBack,  _client);

            // How do I return _dataServiceResponse, if I am calling the WCF service
            // asynchronously??

            return _dataServiceResponse;
        }
```

And the callback method signature:

```
void DataServiceQueryCallBack(IAsyncResult result)
{
  // ... implementation code
}
```

Thanks in advance,
John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently I misunderstood the original question, which was about how to use the asynchronous methods on a client proxy.

The answer is that you *don't* return from an asynchronous method call.  It wouldn't be asynchronous if you could.  If you are trying to encapsulate an asynchronous method on a WCF client, then you should encapsulate a callback instead of a return value:

```
public interface IDataService
{
    void SendDataRequest(Action<IDataServiceResponse> callback);
}

public class DataService
{
    public void SendDataRequest(Action<IDataServiceResponse> callback)
    {
        InitializeDataServiceParameters();
        _client.BeginQueryJobs(_parameters, DataServiceQueryCallBack, callback);
    }

    private void DataServiceQueryCallBack(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        var response = _client.EndQueryJobs(ar);
        // Convert the actual WCF response into your custom interface
        var dataServiceResponse = TranslateResponse(response);
        Action<IDataServiceResponse> callback = 
            (Action<IDataServiceResponse>)result.AsyncState;
        if (callback != null)
            callback(dataServiceResponse);
    }
}
```